# Why does Google Drive api keep getting userRateLimitExceeded error?

Tags: permissions, google-drive-api

I'm making a service that mainly uses Google Drive API. Share files by inserting and subtracting share permissions for multiple files on personal drive. But there is an error in certain users' accounts. This error is an error that occurs in the process of creating and inserting Google drive permission. I tried all the solutions suggested by Google drive support. Delete cache, delete cookies, use another browser, wait 24 hours before using etc. I've tried everything, but it's not working and the error rate of the service is increasing. Who can tell me how to solve this problem?

error response :

> {
>
> "code" : 403,
>
> "errors" : [ {
>
> "domain" : "usageLimits",
>
> "location" : "user",
>
> "locationType" : "other",
>
> "message" : "User rate limit exceeded",
>
> "reason" : "userRateLimitExceeded"
>
> } ],
>
> "message" : "User rate limit exceeded"
>
> }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> User rate limit exceeded

This error is flood protection. [Resolve a 403 error: User rate limit exceeded](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/handle-errors#resolve_a_403_error_user_rate_limit_exceeded)

The solution would be to slow down and implement [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/limits#exponential) and retry the request.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73685072/quota-of-requests-google-api-is-exceed-by-few-requests) that was exactly the same as  my problem situation, and I found that the respondent was the same as you. Thank you for helping to clarify the issue. I have to solve this problem, but I think it's the beginning of solving the problem by clarifying the situation.